# Simple Injector - Injecting ISecureDataFormat into AccountController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am currently working on setting up an MVC 5 project with Web API 2 and Identity 2.0.  In the template, the Account Controller constructor has two parameters - ApplicationUserManager and ISecureDataFormat.

```
public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
```

I have added Simple Injector to my mostly default project and began cleaning up my controllers for dependency injection.  However, I cannot for the life of my figure out how to inject the ISecureDataFormat interface.

I have tried quite a few things including:

```
container.RegisterWebApiRequest<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>, SecureDataFormat>();
```

But it appears that SecureDataFormat no longer exists as of the most recent version of MVC.  Has anyone been able to track down how to inject this interface?

Thanks!

Comment: You only need the `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>` in case you need the `AddExternalLogin` functionality. If you don't need that, you can simply remove this argument from the constructor.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks a ton for the suggestion.  I in fact do not plan on using the AddExternalLogin functionality.  I will give removing it and the external ends points this evening and let you know.  Thanks so much for your suggestion!